# Excel: Dropdown style selector

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Currently I am using Data Validation to select from a list of options a cell can be. Is it possible to do the same thing but with styles? I.e. from the dropdown I can select a subset of styles I would like to apply to the cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some code to change the format of some cells, based on the value change of certain cell.

Let's say that you want to change the color of cell `D2` based on the value of cell `B2` (both in `Sheet1`). Open your VBA editor, double click on "Sheet1" of your book in your Project browser and select the `Worksheet` object and the `Change` procedure, and do something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then ' This is the address of the cell being changed
        Select Case Target.Value
            Case 1 ' The changed cell value is 1
                ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("d2").Interior.Color = RGB(125, 125, 125)
            Case 2 ' The changed cell value is 2
                ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("d2").Interior.Color = RGB(125, 125, 255)
            Case 3 ' The changed cell value is 3
                ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("d2").Interior.Color = RGB(125, 0, 255)
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

You can google around to find ways to change other format properties of the cell.